# Help Integration in Qt/C++ Application

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, chm

I am using `Qt 4.6` so do C++.

I have a **User Manual** (`.chm`) for my application which has the help required for the users to run the application. Now I want this help to be **integrated into my application**, so that when the user selects for help from the application, the user manual will be opened with  **the corresponding help page displayed**. In this way I can make use of the already available manual and users will find easy to probe through the document. (*since it is familiar*)

The user manual file is in the `.chm` format which has corresponding search keywords, which can be used to display the corresponding page when selected from the application. Just similar to `F1` help in any of the windows application.

**Is it possible to do this in Qt or C++?** Or

**What are the other ways through which the help can be integrated in the application?**

Any pointers regarding this are welcome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The help system infrastructure was designed to integrate with normal Win32 development in Visual Studio, but this is not technically necessary. Basically you just call `HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow(), "Yourhelp.chm", HH_HELP_CONTEXT, IDYourCurrentContext);`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on HtmlHelp() function. Basically am used to Qt but the function does sound like a VC++ one.

Comment: It's not VC++ specific, but a general Win32 API function. Include Htmlhelp.h and link to Htmlhelp.lib (you get these by installing HTML Help workshop, but I presume you already have these if you made a .chm)

Comment: Cool.. Is it possible for me to pass the value for Index item from this function so that it directly loads the desired page??

Comment: The precise value doesn't matter as long as your application and the .chm agree.

Answer (score 1):

The more `Qt` way of Help Integration can also be done which is as follows.

The chm files are always opened by the `hh.exe`

So,

```
QProcess::execute("hh.exe D:/Manual.chm");
```

can be used to open the `Manual.chm` file from the application.

The command

```
QProcess::execute("hh.exe D:/Manual.chm::page1.htm");
```

will open the `chm file` with the **page1.htm** loaded. This will be helpful to load a specific help page in the `chm file`.

The only thing we must be aware in this approach is that we must have known the file name of the web pages (*here* `page1.htm`) previously..

Hope this one also helps... :)

Answer (score 1):

QDesktopServices::openUrl() would be even more Qt way. Then you do not need to specify hh.exe but rely instead on the system file associations to use proper application. Hence - portability, the key thing behind Qt stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try using [libCHMxx](http://www.mare.ee/indrek/libchmxx/) or [CHM lib](http://www.jedrea.com/chmlib/) along with Qt help system (see [this sample](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/help-simpletextviewer.html))