# Creating Documentation Using QtHelp Module

Tags: qt, documentation

Qt provides two kinds of help files: Qt Compressed Help (.qch) and Qt Help Collection (.qhc).
The first one actually contains compressed help data (html pages, images etc). The second one contains references to different compressed help files.

Both Qt Assistant and QHelpEngine are using collection files to display help. So I need at least two files to provide documentation for my application: .qch and .qhc.

I want to have a single help file to be used by Qt Help API (e.g. like a .chm help file in Windows).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to create a chm file using `QtHelp` module since [chm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) files are Microsoft specific and not an independent format.

But all the chm files are opened by the `hh.exe` application that belongs to HTML Help workshop. I have accessed chm files for opening a specified html page using `hh` application.
You can have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351511/help-integration-in-qt-c-application/3361745#3361745) in my answer.

If there are command line options provided by Microsoft to compile chm files either by `hh` or through HTML Help workshop command line (if any), you can do that by running the command in `QProcess`. You have to probe more into that.

Or you can create chm files manually using HTML Help workshop and integrate the chm files into the application.

Hope that helps in giving you a start.

Comment: I think i didn't express what I need clear enough. I don't need any chm files. I just want to have a single help file to be used by Qt Help API (not two files: compressed help + help collection).

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but have a look at [chm2qch](https://bitbucket.org/mitrich_k/chm2qch), Tool for converting Windows CHM files to Qt Help format.